# insert is failing because of my trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I have a problem with my trigger code.
After I wrote my trigger I wrote Insert to test the trigger. But my Insert gets error as

> Error Code:1109. Unknown table `employees` in field list.

If I put the insert before the trigger-everything works perfect. But I want this Insert to test the trigger.

```
    drop database if exists kontrolno;
    create database kontrolno;
    use kontrolno;
    CREATE TABLE departments(
    id TINYINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    name CHAR(12) NOT NULL,
    min_salary SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    max_salary SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
    CREATE TABLE employees(
    id SMALLINT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    salary SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    department_id TINYINT UNSIGNED,
    constraint FOREIGN KEY (department_id)
    REFERENCES departments(id)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

   insert into departments(id,name,min_salary,max_salary)
   values(1,"qa", 800,2000),
   (2,"jd",1200,3500);


   DROP TRIGGER if exists checkSalary;
   delimiter |
   create trigger checkSalary before Insert on employees
   for each row
   begin

   if(employees.salary>max_salary OR employees.salary<min_salary)
   then signal sqlstate '45000' set MESSAGE_TEXT="the salary is not valide";
    end if;
   end;
    |
  delimiter ;

   insert into employees(id,name,salary,department_id)
   values(1,"ivan", 200,1);
```

Comment: why you are using `if(employees.salary>max_salary OR employees.salary<min_salary)` ? what is the logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had mistakes in your trigger code.
The trigger code should be:

```
DROP TRIGGER if exists checkSalary;
delimiter |
create trigger checkSalary before Insert on employees
for each row
begin

if(new.salary>(select max_salary from departments where id=new.department_id)
   OR 
   new.salary<(select min_salary from departments where id=new.department_id) )
 then signal sqlstate '45000' set MESSAGE_TEXT="the salary is not valid";

end if;
end;
 |
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much !